# Adding a selectable 'not found' entry to a Twitter Typeahead Control

Tags: javascript, typeahead.js, bloodhound

I've been combining Twitter Typeahead and Bloodhound into a Knockout custom binding as a bit of an experiment, and so far I have it working quite well. However I have a use case where I wanted to have a selectable entry in the list if a user types in a search term which finds no results. This isn't something that is available by default in typeahead but I did find [this issue on Github](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/747) which demonstrates a workaround that seems to fit the bill.  Trouble is I can't get it to work at all and my fairly limited Javascript smarts have all but run out.

The gist of this workaround is that rather than creating a Bloodhound instance and then setting the `source` property of the typeahead to `engine.ttAdaptor()` you do the following:

```
var engine = new Bloodhound(/* ... */);
engine.initialize();

var emptyDatum = { val: 'i am suggestion shown when there are none!' };

var sourceWithEmptySelectable = function(q, cb) {
    engine.get(q, injectEmptySelectable);

    function injectEmptySelectable(suggestions) {
        if (suggestions.length === 0) {
            cb([emptyDatum]);
        }
        else {
            cb(suggestions);
        }
     }
};

$('.typeahead').typeahead(null, {
    // ...
    source: sourceWithEmptySelectable
});
```

Using the latest versions of typeahead (v0.11.1) I get an error which simply says `missing source`. Looking at the source code for Bloodhound it looks to me like the `engine.get(q, injectEmptySelectable)` call no longer works as there is no method of `get` on the Bloodhound class with a signature that accepts a query and a callback. There is one on the `Transport` class but I'm not seeing how that would be the one being used in this example. Am I correct in this or am I missing something, or is there another way to accomplish this?